# Why is an event loop needed for Asynchronous I/O

Tags: .net, ruby, asynchronous, eventmachine, event-loop

I've done lots of development in C#/.Net, and the asynchronous story has always been there from day one (admittedly the API's have changed significantly over the years from begin/end to events, to `Task<T>` with `async`/`await`). For the last year or so I've been developing with Node.js which does all I/O asynchronously and uses a single threaded event loop model. Recently I was working on a project where we were using Ruby, and for one part of the application, I felt that it made sense to make a whole bunch of web requests asynchronously, and was surprised to find that the asynchronous story in Ruby is vastly different. The only way to do any asynchronous I/O is by using the `EventMachine`.

My question comes down to this: Why is it that in .Net (and from what I can tell this is true for Java/JVM as well) there's no need for an event loop, and I can fire off an asynchronous request at any time, yet in languages like Ruby/Python, I need to resort to eventmachine/twisted respectively? I feel like there's some fundamental thing about how asynchronous I/O works that I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> My question comes down to this: Why is it that in .Net (and from what
> I can tell this is true for Java/JVM as well) there's no need for an
> event loop, and I can fire off an asynchronous request at any time,
> yet in languages like Ruby/Python, I need to resort to
> eventmachine/twisted respectively?

I think that's because Ruby/Python (and seamlessly, Node.js as well) want to make a developer's life easier by imposing single-threaded model for the application's core loop. With event machine, the completion callbacks of the async I/O routines are serialized and queued to be executed on the same thread, so the developer doesn't have to worry about thread safety.

I can't speak for Java, but in .NET we have control over this with *synchronization context*. Check Stephen Cleary's ["It's All About the SynchronizationContext"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx). It's quite easy to replicate the concept of event machine in .NET (in fact, that's automatically done for UI applications). A custom implementation of the serializing synchronization context might look like `AsyncPump` from Stephen Toub's ["Await, SynchronizationContext, and Console Apps"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/). IMO, this would be a direct match to Ruby's event machine.

Comment: So if I'm reading correctly between the lines, you're saying that in .Net, let's say in a simple Console application, if you make an asynchronous I/O request, there's another thread involved and that's something that Ruby/Python want to avoid? I guess my confusion is that I always thought that when making an asynchronous I/O request .Net, there was no need for any additional threads.

Comment: @BFree, your follow-up is correct. In a simple console app, if you `await` the result of an async I/O API which you called on a thread without synchronization context (`SynchronizationContext.Current == null`), the `await` continuation callback will be called on a random thread where the operation has actually completed. Most likely, this is going to be an IOCP pool thread, different from the thread you started on. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22475242/1768303) for some more details. If you don't like that, you have freedom to enroll your own sync. context like `AsyncPump`.

Comment: There is a nice [example of event loop implementation](https://github.com/yuriy-nelipovich/single-sand) in .net, it has an example of console TCP server that is running on the main thread. All IOCP events are _redirected_ to the event loop so that it performs much like ruby. As Noseratio said, this is no way to get rid of this _redirection_.

Answer (score 2):

`EventMachine` is not the only way to do asynchronous IO in Ruby. You could fork another process or spawn a new thread. Of course you would need to handle and coordinate the subsequent communication.

EventMachine is just one of the alternative concurrency implementations available to Ruby, based on the [reactor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern). It allows for non-blocking IO, *without using any threads, in a single process*. The main advantage is that you get rid of the [complexity associated with multithreading](http://www.slideshare.net/autonomous/ruby-concurrency-and-eventmachine), including deadlocks, race conditions, Ruby's infamous GIL, and debugging nightmares.

[Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh191443.aspx) in .NET offer a similar functionality which does not require multithreading, while [Task.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run.aspx) or [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) follow a threaded approach.

As with every question worth pondering, each approach has its benefits and use cases. If you intend to perform a *CPU-bound* operation on the background you might be better off spawning a new thread. If you need to perform *IO-bound* operations then a reactor-based approach will be more suitable (and definitely less complex).

Comment: _You could fork another process or spawn a new thread_ That's not asynchronous I/O. That's Synchronous I/O on a background thread. That thread will still block and then you have all the overhead of context switching etc. All operating systems have support for Asynchronous I/O and C#/.Net exposes that, whereas Ruby/Python does not. Why? That's my question.

Comment: @BFree it is still a form of async IO, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O#Forms