# How does .NET handle IOCP thread safety?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, iocp

I'm playing with `SocketAsyncEventArgs` and IO Completion Ports.
I've been looking but I can't seem to find how .NET handles race conditions.

Need clarification on this stack overflow question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28690948/855421

> As a side note, don't forget that your request might have completed synchronously. Perhaps you're reading from a TCP stream in a while loop, 512 bytes at a time. **If the socket buffer has enough data in it, multiple ReadAsyncs can return immediately without doing any thread switching at all.** *[emphasis mine]*

For the sake of simplicity. Let's assume one client one server. The server is using a IOCP. If the client is a fast writer but server is a slow reader, does IOCP mean the kernel/underlying process can signal multiple threads?

```
1 So, socket reads 512 bytes, kernel signals a IOCP thread
2 Server processes new bytes
3 socket receives another X bytes but server is still processing previous buffer
```

Does the kernel spin up another thread? `SocketAsyncEventArgs` has a `Buffer` which by definition is: "Gets the data buffer to use with an asynchronous socket method." So the buffer should not change over the lifetime of the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` if I understand that correctly.

What's preventing `SocketAsyncEventArgs.Buffer` from getting corrupted by IOCP thread 2?

Or does the .NET framework synchronize IOCP threads? If so, what's the point of spinning up a new thread then if IOCP thread 1 blocks the previous read?

Comment: I believe the linked answer is referring to the process of calling `ReadAsync` multiple times in succession - not of having multiple `ReadAsync` calls outstanding *at the same time* on the *same* connection. If you do that, you have no idea what order data was received in (although I believe you're still safe from any corruption issues)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I believe there should be one ReadAsync per socket. But the explanations I've read seem to say one ReadAsync can spin multiple IOCP threads. And I don't understand why you'd want that.

Comment: Well, I can't account for where/what you've read, especially with no links to such provided. Why are you trying to dig down so deep? The contract is that you call `ReadAsync` with a particular target number of bytes and you'll get notification when some other number (or possibly the same number) of bytes have been delivered. If there's any threading issues to deal with (I don't believe there are), they've being dealt with by the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've been looking but I can't seem to find how .NET handles race conditions.

For the most part, it doesn't. It's up to you to do that. But, it's not clear from your question that you really have a race condition problem.

You are asking about this text, in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28690948/855421):

> If the socket buffer has enough data in it, multiple ReadAsyncs can return immediately without doing any thread switching at all

First, to be clear: the method's name is `ReceiveAsync()`, not `ReadAsync()`. Other classes, like `StreamReader` and `NetworkStream` have `ReadAsync()` methods, and these methods have very little to do with what your question is about. Now, that clarified…

That quote is about the *opposite* of a race condition. The author of that text is warning you that, should you happen to call `ReceiveAsync()` on a socket that already has data ready to be read, the data will be read synchronously and the `SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed` event will *not* be raised later. It will be the responsibility of the thread that called `ReceiveAsync()` to also process the data that was read.

All of this would happen in a single thread. There wouldn't be any race condition in that scenario.

Now, let's consider your "fast writer, slow reader" scenario. The worst that can happen there is that the first read, which could take place in any thread, does not complete immediately, but by the time the `Completed` event is raised, the writer has overrun the reader's pace. In this case, since part of handling the `Completed` event is likely to be calling `ReceiveAsync()` again, which now will return synchronously, an IOCP thread pool thread will get tied up looping on the calls to `ReceiveAsync()`. No new thread is needed, because the current IOCP thread is doing all the work synchronously. But it *does* prevent that thread from handling *other* IOCP events.

All that will mean though, is that if you have some *other* socket the server is handling and which also needs to call `ReceiveAsync()`, the framework will have to ensure there's another thread in the IOCP thread pool available to handle that I/O. But, that's a completely different socket and you would necessarily be using a completely different buffer for that socket anyway.

Again, no race condition.

Now, all that said, if you want to get *really* confused, it *is* possible to use asynchronous I/O in the .NET `Socket` API (whether with `BeginReceive()` or `ReceiveAsync()` or even wrapping the socket in a `NetworkStream` and using `ReadAsync()`) in such a way that you *do* have a race condition for a particular socket.

I hesitate to even mention it, because there's no evidence in your question this pertains to you at all, nor that you're even really interested in having this level of detail. Adding this explanation could just confuse things. But, for the sake of completeness…

It is possible to have issued more than one read operation on a socket at any given time. This would be somewhat akin to double- or triple-buffered video display (if you're familiar with that concept). The idea being that you might still be handling a read operation while new data comes in, and it would be more performant to have a new read operation already in progress to handle that data before you're done handling the current read operation.

This sounds great, but in practice because of the way Windows schedules threads, and in particular does not guarantee a particular ordering of thread scheduling, if you try to implement your code that way, you create the possibility that *your* code will see read operations completed out of order. That is, if you for example call `ReceiveAsync()` twice in a row (with two different `SocketAsyncEventArgs` objects and two different buffers, of course), your `Completed` event handler might get called with the second buffer first.

This isn't because the read operations themselves complete out of order. They don't. Hence the emphasis on *"your"* above. The problem is that while the IOCP threads handling the IO completions become runnable in the correct order (because the buffers are filled in the order you provided them by calling `ReceiveAsync()` multiple times), the second IOCP thread to become runnable could wind up being the *first* thread to actually be scheduled to run by Windows.

This is not hard to deal with. You just have to make sure that you track the buffer sequence as you issue the read operations, so that you can reassemble the buffers in the correct order later. All of the async options available provide a mechanism for you to include additional user state data (e.g. `SocketAsyncEventArgs.UserToken`), so you can use this to track the order of your buffers.

Again, this is not common. For most scenarios, a completely orderly implementation, where you only issue a new read operation after you're completely done with the current read operation, is completely sufficient. If you're worried at all about getting a multi-buffer read implementation correct, just don't bother. Stick with the simple approach.

Comment: The confusion of concepts/levels in the question makes me suspect that this is an A/Y problem - like an X/Y problem, but even X is far divorced from the problem that they were originally dealing with.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It more or less answers my question.

Comment: *.. the writer has overrun the reader's pace. In this case, since part of handling the Completed event is likely to be calling ReceiveAsync() again, which now will return synchronously, an IOCP thread pool thread will get tied up looping on the calls to ReceiveAsync(). No new thread is needed, because the current IOCP thread is doing all the work synchronously. But it does prevent that thread from handling other IOCP events.* - Exactly what I wanted to know

Comment: _"Not sure why this was downvoted"_ -- me either. It's possible @Damien felt I'd failed to get at the heart of what you actually needed. It's also possible it was just a random, retaliatory down-vote, which I get from time to time because of moderating activities I've done elsewhere (such as down-voting a poor question or voting to close, that sort of thing), and has nothing to do with any actual perceived quality of the answer. In any case, I'm happy I was able to address what you wanted to know.

Comment: Thanks for the almost perfectly detailed answer. This question is definitely going into StackStalker due to this answer.